# Creating enterprise init script (to support all Linux distros)

Tags: linux, shell-scripting, best-practices, init.d

I'd like to create my own init script to make my program start at boot and be controlled via "service" utility in most popular Linux distributions.

Requirements:

- it should be portable across different distros(it should support at
  least Debian/Ubuntu and RedHat/Centos)
- it shouldn't depend on any
  additionally installed packages
- it should control if my program
  started succesfully or encountered some kind of errors
- it should
  reliably stop my program when requested (sometimes init script say
  "stopping... OK" but it's still running)

For example, I can do it this way:

```
case "$1" in
start)
    ./start-jira.sh
    ;;
stop)
    ./stop-jira.sh
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

But in this case it's required to check if program has been properly started with 'ps' and properly killed on shutdown.

Looking for the right way to do it. Is there any standard to satisfy all those systemd, upstart,etc. ?

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html

Comment: @Federico Sierra will it support systemd, upstart and all other popular init variants?

Answer (score 0):

There's no drop-in script that will work with all init systems.
While you can write one that launches your daemon (similar to bin/startup.sh for tomcat), you need some config files or scripts for the actual init system in use by the target distro.